# Is there any way to access database of an application from another application in iOS, with objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database

I separated some processes. I have two application and i want to access database of one of them from another. Is there any way to access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot access database in one app from another app.

However there are always workarounds, such as using [UIPasteboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html)

> The UIPasteboard class enables an application to share data within the
>   application or with another application using system-wide or
>   application-specific pasteboards.

1. First you will need to create an application-specific pasteboard by `pasteboardWithName:create:`
2. You can then save your database in one app, and convert it to NSData, then put it into your application-specific pasteboard with `setData:forPasteboardType:`
3. You can read the NSData with `dataForPasteboardType:` and convert it back to your database format

Hope this help.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is **NO.**

Each and every application in iOS is sandboxed, hence one app cannot access data of another one.

(I think it can be done on jail broken device).

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot directly access database from one application to another.

But, you can achieve sync process between two application, by sending data from first application to server and fetching same data from server in your second application through web services.

Hope this info helps you..

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done directly, but you can share files between applications.
You can register your application to handle particular file types (e.g. *.sqlite files).

For example you can open attachments from Mail.app in other application like GoodReader or something else.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html) is more info

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot access contents from one application to another, as they are limited to itself.